# PostgreSQL перестал работать

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL перестал работать почему-то.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
C:\Users\Tim>psql -h localhost -U postgres postgres
psql: не удалось подключиться к серверу: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Он действительно работает по адресу "localhost" (::1) и принимает TCP-соединения (порт 5432)?
```

Comment: Он не запущен, по всей видимости.

Comment: Could not connect to PostgreSQL.
Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to PostgreSQL. (Error: Подсоединение по адресу localhost:5432 отклонено. Проверьте что хост и порт указаны правильно и что postmaster принимает TCP/IP-подсоединения.)

Comment: Что делать? Непонятно)

Comment: Запустить постгрес?

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: А как вы его устанавливали?

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте выполнить:

```
pg_ctl start
```